# Capybara element not found haml button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, haml

I have a diagnostic spec and i believe there is some inconsistency in my use of the language between the spec and the view files. However i have not been able to resolve the problem. The test is as follows

```
it "updates a diagnostic report" do 
diagnostic_info = FG.create(:diagnostic_info)
diagnostic_info.save!
visit edit_admin_diagnostic_path(diagnostic_info)
fill_in 'diagnostic_info_notes',    with: "test notes"
click_button "Save" 
page.should have_content("Saved")
page.should have_content("test notes")
```

end

the view is

```
.field
    = label_tag :notes
    = f.text_field "notes"
    = submit_tag @diagnostic.data["Save"], method: :put, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }
```

and the failure is

```
1) /admin/diagnostics updates a diagnostic report
 Failure/Error: click_button "Save"
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find button "Save"
```

I have been trying to change the syntax in the view file so that the submit tag is instead a button. This is because i thought the problem was the use of tag rather than button. However I have not been able to do this with haml syntax successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails has [built in support](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) for localization and internationalization. No need to roll your own.

```
# app/views/diagnostics/edit.haml.erb
.field
    = label_tag :notes
    = f.text_field "notes"
    = submit_tag I18n.t('.save'), method: :put, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }
```

The translations are stored in YAML files located in `config/locales`.

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  diagnostics:
    edit:
      save: 'Save'
```

You can also use your translations in your specs:

```
it "updates a diagnostic report" do 
  diagnostic_info = FG.create(:diagnostic_info)
  diagnostic_info.save!
  visit edit_admin_diagnostic_path(diagnostic_info)
  fill_in 'diagnostic_info_notes',    with: "test notes"
  click_button I18n.t('diagnostics.edit.save') # Note that we need full path
  page.should have_content(I18n.t('diagnostics.edit.save'))
  page.should have_content("test notes")
end
```

Comment: do you mean i should add that to the config/locales/en.yml?

Comment: Thanks, i just did this but it still gives me the same capybara error unfortunately

Comment: Did you try checking the html output by `print page.html`?

Comment: Also the lookup path in `config/locales/en.yml` actually has to match what your views are called or Rails will fail to find the translation.